# Erratum in the book Learning Python in format expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I am reading the book "Learning Python 5th edition" and came across(what I think) contradictory statement quoted below.

On Page 152 it is written that:

> Finally, you can also convert integers to base-specific strings with string formatting method calls and expression, **which return just digits, not Python literal string**:
>
> ```
> >>> '%o, %x, %x, %X' % (64, 64, 255, 255)
> '100, 40, ff, FF'
> ```

(emphasis mine)

As we can see in the above highlighted(in bold) statement, the author says that string formatting method calls and expression return "digits" and not "literal string". But I find that incorrect because we can clearly see that the result '100, 40, ff, FF' is a string indeed and not a "digit".

---

Moreover, on Page 156 the author seems to be writing completely opposite:

> string formatting produces a string, not a number:
>
> ```
> >>> ('%.2f' % (1 / 3.0))
> '0.33'
> ```

As we can see in the second quoted statement, the author now says that string formatting produces a "string" and not a "number" which seems contradictory to their first statement(on page 152).

So my question is that is this an erratum in the book and which of the two statements is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly as it's written, because it doesn't even make sense grammatically?

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> type('%o, %x, %x, %X' % (64, 64, 255, 255))
    <class 'str'>
```

python tells, this formatted string is a `string`-type. Obviously, it can not be any other type.

same result is returned for the other string.

```py
>>> type(('%.2f' % (1 / 3.0)))
    <class 'str'>
```

Author is trying to highlight the significance of string formatting methods. Formatting methods are not returning *numeral*-types, but also converting them to *string*-type.

As a quick solution, I would suggest to omit the portion of sentence you have emphasized ("*which return just digits, not Python literal string*"). That will effectively remove your confusion without compromising any other fact.

You need to always keep in mind that a string formatting methods will always return a `string`-type only.

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem.

Comment: Added some explanation.